# How to import photos from iPhone 3G to iPhoto in Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, photos.app, iphone

I have a still fully useable iPhone 3G (2008). I take snapshots daily, and used to put them into iPhoto on my 2008 white MacBook with OS X 10.5.8.

Recently, I started using a 2012 MacBook Pro (not Retina) with Mavericks installed, by now Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Ny iPhone and My Mac do not recognize each other. iPhoto does not open when connecting my iPhone. The iPhone is not seen as an external device in Finder.

How can I transfer the 5,000 photos on my iPhone to iPhoto on that Mac?

Comment: Have you tried opening iPhoto manually with the iPhone connected? It should recognize it. Finder never mounts iPhone camera rolls as volumes.

Comment: there is another App preinstalled on every mac - calles Image Capture - where you can "download" all Images from your iDevice

Answer (score -4):

Photos Version 1.0.1 (215.65.0) seems to have no way to import from an attached device anymore.

Comment: The question is about iPhoto actually.